# Python - Direct nested function call

Tags: python, nested-function

I want to call a nested function directly, like this:

`Template('/path/to/file').expect('key').to_be_in('second_key')`

`Template('/path/to/file').expect('key').to_be('value')`

I tried this:

```
class Template(object):
  def __init__(self, path):
    self.content = json.load(open(path, 'r'))

  def expect(self, a):
    def to_be_in(b):
      b = self.content[b]
      return a in b

    def to_be(b):
      a = self.content[b]
      return a == b
```

But I get the following error:

```
Template('~/template.json').expect('template_name').to_be_in('domains')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_be_in'
```

How to achieve that in Python ?

Comment: That nested function does not exist outside the parent function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return an object which provides a `to_be_in` member that is a function, to wit (example only):

```
class Template_Expect(object):
    def __init__(self, template, a):
        self.template = template
        self.a = a

    def to_be_in(self, b):
        b = self.template.content[b]
        return self.a in b

    def to_be(self, b):
        a = self.template.content[b]
        return a == b

class Template(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.content = json.load(open(path, 'r'))

    def expect(self, a):
        return Template_Expect(self, a)
```

Comment: That's literally exactly what I just wrote on my notepad. Thanks !